# getting data in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following:

```
id  bill vote
1    x   1
2    y   1
3    y   0
4    z   1
5    x   1
```

What I want the query to return is:

```
bill  vote(1) vote(0)
x     2       0
y     1       1
z     1       0
```

vote(1) is count of data (1), same applies to vote(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select bill, sum(vote) as vote_1, sum(1-vote) as vote_0
from tablename
group by bill
```

The first sum is used to sum all 1's. The second one to sum all 0's (1-1 = 0, 1 - 0 = 1!)

Comment: ty @jarlh. This worked. Is there any explanation to the form of query you suggested?

Comment: Read about GROUP BY and aggregate functions (e.g. SUM.)